# Link Aggregation (Bonding) of OpenVPN TAP devices in Windows XP

Tags: networking, windows-xp, openvpn, bonding

Is there any way to bond two TAP devices in Windows XP into one network device?

My ISP is, in theory, providing me with a 5Mb/s connection. However, my OpenVPN tap device can only reach ~100KB/s. However, I've tried connecting two devices, and each one can sustain the same 100KB/s.

In Linux, I can bond them together and get, for all practical purposes, a 200KB/s connection. Is there any way to do this in Windows XP?

Comment: Your ISP is likely providing you with an asynchronous connection so that 5Mbps connection is likely around 500Kbps to 1Mbps up, 5Mbps down.  100Kbps throughput on a VPN connection isn't that horrible, what with the encryption overhead, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that the 100KB/s is the download speed. By running two downloads over two tunnels, I can download 200KB/s easil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to accomplish this in Windows without additional software. I'm not aware of any bonding software that would work on OpenVPN TAP interfaces (though it might exist).